# Using Redis and Perl, how to wait for one published method

Tags: perl, redis

I want to do something that is conceptually quite simple, wait for up to thirty seconds for a redid publish to come through. As soon as it comes through, I want to return, or if it doesn't come through, I want to return after thirty seconds.

The perl [Redis](http://search.cpan.org/~dams/Redis-1.981/lib/Redis.pm) module has almost everything that I want, except that I cannot return immediately after I get a message in.

The sample code that I am using looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Redis;

my $redisSub = Redis->new;
my $msg = 0;
my @topics = ('mykey');
my $savecallback = sub {
  my ($message, $topic, $subscribed_topic) = @_;
  print "Message received : $message\n";
  $msg = $message;
  # I tried adding in the following line, but it complains
  # that: Missing required callback in call to unsubscribe()
  #$redisSub->unsubscribe ( @topics , $savecallback);
};
$redisSub->subscribe ( @topics , $savecallback);

my $redis = Redis->new;
print "old: " . $redis->get('mykey') . "\n";
print "Waiting for message to be sent\n";
$redisSub->wait_for_messages(30);

if ($msg) {
  print "old: " . $redis->get('mykey') . "\n";
} else {
  print "Timeout occurred\n";
}
```

The issue is that the `wait_for_messages(30)` call waits for thirty seconds of idle activity, so if the message turns up, it prints out, immediately, "Message received", but then waits another thirty seconds before returning control to the script. I could change it to `wait_for_messages(0)`, but then it returns immediately, and I need to includes this in a sleep loop, which introduces the potential latency in detecting the change outside of the call.

Is this possible using only the Redis module? Or does one need to use the [AnyEvent::Redis::PipeRedis](http://search.cpan.org/~iph/AnyEvent-Redis-RipeRedis-1.254/lib/AnyEvent/Redis/RipeRedis.pm) module to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans : There is no such latency as you have mentioned. To stop with no more waiting when message arrives, use unsubscribe() but I have not tested it.

How : You have to do this:

```
while ('true' ) {
$redisSub->wait_for_messages(30); 
}
```

Why: The above waits for messages for 30 seconds, after that another 30 seconds and so on. But whenever a subscribed event happened, instantly the call-back-subroutine is invoked but wait_for_messages continues from the original state (independent of invoking/event occured/event not occurred). **wait_for_messages(n) will not return in n seconds if subscribed messages are coming**. So it continues for 30 seconds of wait. So if a matching publish happened every 29 seconds for 10 times, the wait_for_messages will return only after 290+30 seconds with return value 10. (then because of of while('true') it will go back to wait again.)

```
Note :1) Do/should not add sleep in the above code.
Note :2) If your aim is to stop processing after receiving first
message, you have to use $redisSub->unsubscribe(..) 
inside the call-back-subroutine.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer my question though. Essentially what I want is to wait for up to 30 seconds for one message, and then to continue immediately once it arrives.

Comment: continue what immediately? what is not happening that you expect/want to happen?

Comment: Basically I wanted to use this as a messaging solution, so I want to wait for the message, and then do some processing. So I only want to wait for _one_ message, so once it is received, I can stop waiting. Except that I can't.

Comment: In call-back-subroutine you must call $redisSub->unsubscribe(..) to accomplish what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Finally this is what worked for this requirement: // I do not want to continue waiting after the event occurred//

```
# inside call back sub:
my $savecallback = sub {
  $event_occured = 1 ;  # this is important
  $redisSub->unsubscribe(@topics,$savecallback) ; # as well as this.
  my ($message, $topic, $subscribed_topic) = @_;
...
};
# The above function will not work. Because $savecallback referred inside is undefined before it was assigned since RHS is still in compilation. So the correct one:
sub savecallback {
  $event_occured = 1 ;  # this is important
  $redisSub->unsubscribe(@topics,\&savecallback) ; # as well as this.
  my ($message, $topic, $subscribed_topic) = @_;
...
};
.....

$redisSub->subscribe(@topics,\&savecallback) ;
$event_occurred = 0;
while ( ! event_occurred ) {
$redisSub->wait_for_messages(1); 
}
```

Still the code waits for 1 whole second after calling call-back-subroutine, but I think it is ok.
Without unsubscribe() the code will never return if events are consistently happening in less than a second.

Comment: In the question I stated that "  # I tried adding in the following line, but it complains
  # that: Missing required callback in call to unsubscribe()
  #$redisSub->unsubscribe ( @topics , $savecallback);"

Comment: Paul, yes, you have mentioned. sorry missing it. But I guess you are trying to do something a little bit over ambitious. The $savecallback is assigned a reference to a sub routine after the right side is compiled. But inside the sub routine you are mentioning the call back subroutines name, which is not referring to anything yet. So from inside the subroutine, at this point **$redisSub->unsubscribe ( @topics , $savecallback);** $savecallback is a null. So we need to name the sub-routine and use it's reference with \&.

Comment: @PaulWagland If I am not asking toomuch, did this come close to solve the problem?

Comment: You can have the subroutine callback variable used within the callback itself, but you need to predeclare it. So, something like `my $savecallback; $savecallback = sub { # etc... }`